# Laravel served by nginx in docker only displaying start page

Tags: laravel, docker, nginx

So in docker-compose.yml I have these 2 entries:

```
  nginx:
      image: nginx
      volumes:
      - ./app:/var/www/html:delegated
      - ./config/nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
      ports:
        - "444:444"
      depends_on:
        - laravel
  laravel:
      image: php:8-fpm
      volumes:
        - ./app:/var/www/html:delegated
      ports:
        - "4444:4444"
```

The config file for nginx looks like this:

```
server {
    index index.php;
    listen 444 ssl;
    server_name local.myapp;
    root /var/www/html/public;
    ssl_certificate     /root/ssl/certificate.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /root/ssl/key.pem;
    ssl_protocols       TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers         HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;
        root /var/www/html/public;
        fastcgi_pass laravel:4444;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 900s;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

What happens is that when I go to https://local.myapp:444 I can see the start page for laravel according to the specified route in app/routes/web.php:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
```

However, having this:

```
Route::get('/wel', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
```

When I go to "https://local.myapp:444/wel" it results in a "404 Not Found".

It must be something in the default.conf that is wrong but I cannot see what.

Comment: Check the nginx logs: nginx logs can be found in the default location `/var/log/nginx/access.log and /var/log/nginx/error.log` or in the location specified in the nginx configuration. Check these logs to see if there are any errors related to the /wel route.

Answer (score 0):

Adding:

```
location / {
     try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
}
location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
    try_files $uri /index.php =404;
```

Made the trick.